# перевод денег на мобильный телефон в rails приложении

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, webmoney

Какие инструменты используются в rails приложении для перевода денег на счет мобильного телефона?

Comment: Это больше зависит от **откуда**, а не **куда**, но ничего Rails-специфичного в вопросе нет. Практически любое средство можно приспособить к Rails тем или иным способом.

Comment: В идеале с банковской карты, скажем, Сбербанка. Я нашел вариант с массовыми платежами Яндекс-денег, но там комиссия 4%.